# Modificar total de un campo en base a valores de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

tengo la siguiente situación y duda la cual les explicaré a modo de ejemplo.
Tengo una tabla que contiene datos de facturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y otra tabla donde se guardan los pagos que se aplican a dichas facturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es parecido a la siguiente imagen:

```
SELECT FACTURA,SALDO_PENDIENTE WHERE FECHA_FACTURA BETWEEN '01-09-2019' AND '03-09-2019'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mostrar las facturas en base a un rango de fecha y que a su vez se consideren los pagos aplicados a éstas también dentro de ese mismo rango para que el total se vea afectado.

Se trata de algo parecido a un estado de cuenta pero en este caso las facturas deben mostrarse una sola vez al igual que su total.

Agradecería si pudieran darme sugerencias acerca de cómo puedo obtener esta información para adecuarla a mi información real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo te agrego la respuesta.
Como nota el F2 debe de dar 250 y no 300 como en tu imagen por que veo que se le quita 50.

```
DECLARE @TablaFactura TABLE
(
Factura NVARCHAR(50),
FechaFactura DATE,
Total INT
)
--INSRTANDO DATOS DE EJEMPLO
INSERT INTO @TablaFactura VALUES('F1','01/09/2019',10000),('F2','01/09/2019',300),('F4','03/09/2019',500)

--CREMOA LA TABLA PAGOS
DECLARE @Pagos TABLE
(
Pago NVARCHAR(50),
Fecha_Pago DATE,
FacturaAfectada NVARCHAR(50),
Monto INT
)

INSERT INTO @Pagos VALUES('P1','01/09/2019','F1',100),('P2','02/09/2019','F1',2000),('P3','05/09/2019','F2',50)


SELECT F.Factura,ISNULL(MAX(F.Total)-(SUM(P.Monto)),MAX(F.Total))  AS SALDO_PENDIENTE
FROM @TablaFactura F 
LEFT JOIN @Pagos P ON P.FacturaAfectada=F.Factura AND P.Fecha_Pago BETWEEN '01-09-2019' AND '03-09-2019'
WHERE F.FechaFactura BETWEEN '01-09-2019' AND '03-09-2019'  
GROUP BY  F.Factura
```

Ejemplo :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e3cd35eb37cce0553bb9df2b9d3bc246

Uso tablas tipo variable para no crear las tablas verifica y espero tus comentarios.

Saludos

Comment: No, debe dar 300, según lo que dice el AP, los pagos también hay que tomarlos hasta el 3/9, por lo que el de 50 no entraría. Por otro lado, te recomiendo agregar el `ISNULL`, ya que si no existen pagos el saldo final sería `NULL`.

Comment: Cierto no vi esa parte ahora lo corrijo.

Comment: Estimados, agradezco realmente su apoyo, pruebo el código y retroalimento. Saludos.

Comment: @Jonsin, si la respuesta de Edgar te ha ayudado, te sugiero que la aceptes, haciendo click en el "tilde" que está debajo de lo flechas con el número de votos. Saludos.